# Can you find the missing words?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, pattern, english, word-property

**Given that:**

> $
> \begin{gather}
> \ \text{ art}\hspace{1em}\Leftrightarrow\hspace{1em}\text{phi}
> \end{gather}
> $

**Can you figure out the words that are missing?**

> $
> \begin{gather}
> \text{imps}\hspace{1em}\Leftrightarrow\hspace{1em}\text{???}\\
> \\
> \text{???}\hspace{1em}\Leftrightarrow\hspace{1em}\text{pots}\\
> \\
> \text{aphid}\hspace{1em}\Leftrightarrow\hspace{1em}\text{???}\\
> \\
> \text{???}\hspace{1em}\Leftrightarrow\hspace{1em}\text{matzo}\\
> \end{gather}
> $

**Every answer is a common English word.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the given information we can guess that

> aphid <-> part*
>  which suggests that d equals either s or y.
>  I don't have a conclusive path to disprove y, but if we choose s, we get
>  imps <-> t*ad and pots <-> a*id
>  The first of these suggests that m equals o, and the second seems to verify it, so we substitute into the last unknown to get
>  matzo <-> opi*m, and so z equals u.

Our words are

> toad, amid, parts, and opium.